# Выбор N случайных элементов из списка

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Есть лист, из которого нужно выбрать N уникальных произвольных строк. Проблема в уникальности. В данный момент я придумал только это:

```
public List<String> getRandomElements(int amount, List<String> list) {
    ArrayList<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Random rand = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        if (i > amount * 30) break;
        int index = rand.nextInt(list.size());
        String str = list.get(index);
        if (returnList.contains(str)) {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        returnList.add(str);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

Проблема в том, что иногда код зацикливается. Для этого и придуман костыль, который прерывает цикл. Я хотел бы этого избежать, но не имею понятия как это сделать.

Comment: Магическая константа `30` - это часть костыля, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Regent Думаю, что при среднем значении переменной `amount` 1-5 за 150 рандомов найдется уникальное число) Если там уже больше, то скорее всего там уже нету уникальных значений. Это даже костылем назвать сложно, это так, импровизация, для теста, что-бы сервер не останавливался когда я такое запускаю)

Comment: Есть интересная штука: `Collections.shuffle(list);`. Она бы сильно упростила код. Однако если у вас в массиве миллион элементов, а нужно выбирать 5-10, то использовать перетасовку массива - это перебор. Поэтому вопрос: насколько сильно `amout` меньше длины `list`?

Comment: `list` - максимум 100-200 элементов, `amount` - 0-10. Попробую шаффл, спасибо вам!

Comment: На здоровье. Уже появился ответ с `.shuffle()`, осталось только доработать ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
public List<String> getRandomElements(final int amount, final List<String> list) {
    ArrayList<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>(list);

    Collections.shuffle(returnList); // тут делаем рандом
    if (returnList.size() > amount) { // отрезаем не нужную часть 
    // тут отрезаем не нужную часть
    list.subList(returnList.size() - amount, returnList.size()).clear(); 

    return returnList;
}
```

изменил, что бы функция не трогал основной список.

Comment: @Regent Можно спросить, почему это плохой стиль? А если этот массив, например, создается, заполняется, обрезается и передается куда-то в одной функции? То-есть ниоткуда не приходит и не уходит на след. обработку?

Comment: Спасибо и вам! Работает после неких доработок)

Comment: Если в списке 1 млн. элементов и нужно выбрать только 10 случайных, то эффективность предложенного решения очень низка.

Comment: для таких случаех есть другой метод, менять первые 10 элементов следуюшими случайними элементами. Получится цикл из 10 шагов и результат готов.

Comment: @AlexWells а теперь представьте, что свою функцию вы разместили в библиотеке, которой будут пользоваться другие люди. В названии функции нет ни намёка на то, что массив, переданный в вашу функцию, будет жестоко перемешен и обрезан. Пользователи будут весьма опечалены.

Comment: @AlexWells Второй момент по этому поводу - представьте, что данный метод будет дописывать другой человек и что метод разрастётся по количеству строк. Другой человек будет полагать, что он спокойно может использовать для чего-то переданный в метод аргумент (массив). И каково же будет его удивление, когда при отладке он заметит, что аргумент, который ему нужен, причем в первозданном виде, уже безвозвратно изменён выше. Но первый момент всё же важнее.

Comment: @Regent, понятно, спасибо. Я, впринципе, всегда так и делаю, пытаюсь выносить все в утилсы и тп..

Comment: @Regent для защиты можно объявлять все входные параметры как `final`. Вообще видел мало причин не использовать `final`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin можно, но далеко не во всех языках программирования есть `final` или его аналогия. А вот принцип стоит использовать всегда (`out` в С# - отдельная история). Это первое. Второе: `final` ведь не защитит `List<String> list` от изменения элементов и их порядка внутри списка?

Comment: @Regent согласен, не во всех. Я предлагаю просто дополнительный инструмент, который обеспечивает соблюдение принципа. `List`, конечно, не защищен `final`ом. С точки зрения паранойи можно сразу методу отдавать копию списка. Еще можно метод объявить `final`, чтобы защитить от переопределения.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно не массив строк туда-сюда передавать, а запрашивать массив из N случайных целых чисел от 0 до M, которые могут или не могут повторяться.

Потом с полученными случайными номерами элементов можно делать всё, что угодно классу-клиенту.

Код вечером напишу, не удаляйте пока что как "не-ответ".

Comment: Кажется вечер так и не наступил и на вопрос жалуются тревогами)

Comment: В случае, если в списке есть повторяющиеся строки, этот способ не сработает.