# Вывести n случайных строк из списка строк

Tags: java, массивы, случайные-числа

Допустим есть файл с большим количеством прилагательных (100 штук и более). Считываем из этого файла слова построчно, затем добавляем их в список. Можно ли используя Math.random() выводить n-ное количество слов из списка и как это сделать?

```
try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String strLine;
        ArrayList<String> prilagatelnie = new ArrayList<>();
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            prilagatelnie.add(strLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка");
    }
```

Comment: Так вам нужно вывести n-строк или n-слов?

Comment: В файле с которого я собираюсь считывать будут идти только слова, например:
"абрикосовый
волнующий
зрелый", каждое с новой строки
Получается массив заполняется словами и именно их мне и нужно вывести в случайном порядке (например 1, 43, 94 и 12 слова)

Comment: Можно ли одно прилагательное выводить два и более раз?

Comment: Да можно вывести более двух раз

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выбор N случайных элементов из списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432030/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-n-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получение случайного элемента по размеру списка:

```
int index = (new Random()).nextInt(prilagatelnie.size());    
String randomItem = prilagatelnie.get(index);
```

---

Тестирование алгоритма:

```
java.util.List<String> items = java.util.Arrays.asList(
    "one", "two", "three", "four", "five"
);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int index = (new java.util.Random()).nextInt(items.size());    
    String randomItem = items.get(index);
    
    System.out.println(randomItem);
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже протестировал. То что нужно)

Answer (score 0):

Можно на основе следующего метода (конечно здесь нужно еще добавить обработку исключений)

```
   List<String> getRandomNItem(int n, List<String> prilagatelnie) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            result.add(prilagatelnie.get((int) (Math.random() * n)));
        }
        return result;
    }
```